# How to print different characters using just one for loop

Tags: java

I have to print the following American Flag to the screen:

```
*****=====
*****=====
*****=====
==========
==========
==========
```

(`*****=====` 5 `*`’s and 5 `=`’s) (6 lines in total)

I am only allowed to use one for loop and I cannot use the same `System.out.print();` twice.

Currently I have:

```
for (x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
    System.out.println("*****=====");
}
for (x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
    System.out.println("==========");
}
```

This works, but it has two for loops and I can't figure out how to do it with just one.

Comment: That’s rather unspecific. You could do it even without any loops…

Comment: I know but I've been given these instructions. Basically asking for homework help here!

Comment: Unfortunately not allowed use arrays for this (according to my teacher)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an invitation to be creative.

#### without loop

```
    System.out.println(
        "*****=====\n"
       +"*****=====\n"
       +"*****=====\n"
       +"==========\n"
       +"==========\n"
       +"==========");
```

or

```
    System.out.print("*****");
    System.out.println("=====");
    System.out.print("*****=");
    System.out.println("====");
    System.out.println("*****=====");
    System.out.println("==========");
    System.out.print("=======");
    System.out.println("===");
    System.out.print("=");
    System.out.println("=========");
```

See, no repeating print statement…

#### With one loop

```
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        if(i<3)
            System.out.println("*****=====");
        else
            System.out.println("==========");
```

or, as more experience developers might write it

```
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        System.out.println(i<3? "*****=====": "==========");
```

or, to get bonus points for creativity

```
String string="*****==========";

for(int i=0, s=0; i<6; i++, s=i/3*5)
    System.out.println(string.substring(s, s+10));
```

You see, there are more than one way to achieve a goal… The important thing is that you try to understand how these examples work to add the features of the Java language to your own tool set. Maybe you will create your own alternative solution then.

Comment: The first example with one loop is perfect. As im only a month into college (java is one of my modules) the basics of the basics will do! Interesting to see all the ways of doing it though, will definitely help me in the future, knowing theres always a way around it. Thank you for such a helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` condition inside of your `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
  if (i < 3) {
    System.out.println("*****=====");
  } else {
    System.out.println("==========");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String firstPart = "*****";
String secondPart = "=====";
for (int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println(firstPart + secondPart);
    if (i == 2) {
        firstPart = "=====";  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++)        
    System.out.println(x<4 ? "*****=====" : "=========");
```

or

for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++)System.out.println(x<4 ? "*****=====" : "=========");

Shortest possible I could come up with....